# AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '162e9db178183d33822a3b00b5aed793b1a37971' could not be found for SimpleCaptchaController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am using Simple captcha plugin in Rails3.
<%= show_simple_captcha(:label => "human authentication") %>

I am using the above code in my view file but in the logs I am getting this error.

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '162e9db178183d33822a3b00b5aed793b1a37971' could not be found for SimpleCaptchaController):

Can any body help in this problem.

In routes I am doing

map.simple_captcha '/simple_captcha/:action', :controller => 'simple_captcha'

Comment: check your :action parameter, seems to be md5 hash is set there

Comment: I dont think its some thing about md5.. It may be the problem with the routing.

Comment: I know, I told you to check what exectly you set in :action parameter

Answer (score 0):

You Missed `:action=>"your action name"` in routes Add that and unknown Action problem will be resolved

```
map.simple_captcha '/simple_captcha/:action', :controller => 'simple_captcha', :action=> "your action name"
```

But if you also want to send some params to action add them too like if I also want to send "id" then route will be

```
map.simple_captcha '/simple_captcha/:action/:id', :controller => 'simple_captcha', :action=> "your action name"
```